# Using a for loop to split up a vertical list into separate columns

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to split up a vertical list of 64 numerical values into 8 separate columns of 8 values each using a for loop, but it's not working. Here is my code:

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim row As Integer, col As Integer

col = 65 'column 65 is where all 64 values are located

For row = 2 To 9
        Cells(row, 2).Value = Cells(row, col).Value
Next row

For row = 10 To 17
        Cells(row - 8, 3).Value = Cells(row, col).Value
Next row

For row = 18 To 25
        Cells(row - 16, 4).Value = Cells(row, col).Value
Next row

For row = 26 To 33
        Cells(row - 24, 5).Value = Cells(row, col).Value
Next row

For row = 34 To 41
        Cells(row - 32, 6).Value = Cells(row, col).Value
Next row

For row = 42 To 49
        Cells(row - 40, 7).Value = Cells(row, col).Value
Next row

For row = 50 To 57
        Cells(row - 48, 8).Value = Cells(row, col).Value
Next row

For row = 58 To 65
        Cells(row - 56, 9).Value = Cells(row, col).Value
Next row

End Sub
```

What's the problem here? When I run this, no new columns are created and the original list of 64 values remains unchanged.

Comment: Do you get an error message? It works fine for me, I have some exemplary values in cells `BM2:BM64` and after I run your code they are being properly grouped and displayed in cells `B2:I9`. I also recommend adjusting your code so that it uses `Step`.

Comment: "It's not working" is not descriptive of what *is* happening.  Images would be helpful.

Comment: You aren't qualifying a sheet. Do you have multiple worksheets perhaps, and it's running on one of them just not the one you expect?

Comment: @Cyril The problem is that the list of 64 values isn't being split into smaller columns. There is no difference in the sheet before and after running the macro.

Comment: @JustynaMK I don't get an error message, but the macro isn't working as intended. Please see my previous comment.

Comment: @BruceWayne I only have 1 worksheet active right now. It's very odd as I used the "watch" feature of the VBA debugger to make sure all the variables are incrementing correctly, and they are.

Comment: Thanks @fi12, can you please check if your values are for sure in cells `BM2:BM64` (maybe they are in a different column).

Comment: Consider using the [Range.TextToColumns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.texttocolumns) method.

Comment: @JustynaMK This was the problem! My values were in `BN2:BN64` as I thought column 65 referred to `BN` instead of `BM`. Please post this as answer so I can accept it!

Comment: Also, there's got to be a formula you can use instead. I'm working on one using either `OFFSET()` or `INDIRECT()`...but can't quite crack it.

Comment: Posted, thanks @fi12. Glad this was the only issue.

Comment: @BruceWayne That would be great if you manage to crack it! This approach is quite longwinded but I don't have much experience with VBA.

Comment: @fi12, check my answer below, which condenses the whole code to a few lines.

Answer (score 2):

```vb
Sub Macro1()
Dim row As Integer, col As Integer, i As Integer

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") 'Change to your sheet name.
    col = .Range("BN2").Column 'Change to your column letters as required.
    For row = 2 To 9
        i = (row - 2) * 8 + 2
        .Range(.Cells(2, row), .Cells(9, row)).Value = .Range(.Cells(i, col), .Cells(i + 8, col)).Value
    Next row
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Perhaps so it's a little easier for OP - use `col = Range("BM2").Column`. This resolves to `65`.

Comment: @BruceWayne, OP's actual column turned out to be BN. lol. I would update the answer with this info tough. Thank you ;)

Comment: Good catch.  note that `col` and all the others are slightly better as `Long`. Not really a big deal for this specific case, but `Long` can hold more than `Integer`.  Also `.Col` should just be `Col`: `col = .Range("BN2").Column`

Comment: @BruceWayne, thank you. I usually write all my row, col code as Long. but in this case, the highest number we're dealing with is 65. So I was considering memory optimization. Trade-off, I guess. Thank you again.

Comment: Extremely helpful. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @fi12, I am glad it worked. Good luck. Please consider accepting as answer.

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in the commentary section, the solution is for the "source" data to be in cells `BM2:BM64` (column reference = 65).